# What is the best way to set email template on Case based on the Article attached to the Case without using the QuickActionDefaultHandler?

Tags: servicecloud, casefeed

I am not sure of any way to set a default email template based on the Knowledge Article attached to the Case. The current approach has been to add fields on the Article to reference which email templates should be recommended to the agent. Then when the Knowledge Article is attached to the Case, the agent clicks a custom "email button" and is redirected to a Visualforce page with correct templates available.

I am not sure how I would do this with the QuickActionDefaultHandler because I believe that only lets you pre-populate one template into the Case Feed (for the email to send). Any thoughts on how to do this without custom Visualforce? We lose a lot with going to Visualforce, such as the simple setting of the from address (that is the email address the customer initially emailed). Thanks!